# I just want to have an auto generated User Id with 7 digit number

Tags: c#, ms-access

Just want to ask  how will i make an auto generated account number without changing its type to auto number in my database..

here is my previous code for  making an Id with character:

```
private void AutoIncrementID()
        {
            int rowCount, userID1;
            string userID;

            rowCount = dtgGuest.Rows.Count;
           userID = (dtgGuest.Rows[rowCount-1].Cells[0] .Value.ToString().Substring(1));    
        userID1 = int.Parse(userID);
           userID1 =   userID1+ 1;
            txtAcctNo.Text = "A" + userID1.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Why do you not want to generate it at the database level?  The database is the authoritative source on which IDs are in use and which aren't, regardless of whether the rows have been loaded to your client or not.  It's the best place to generate a new, guaranteed unique ID.

Comment: Using rowcount as the basis for an ID is sure to fail. let the DB do its job

Comment: @Plutonix , yeah I know that but our prof proscribe us not to use the auto number of DB  so we need to come up an alternative to make it auto generated..

Comment: The reason professors limit what you can use to generate ids is so that you may begin thinking like a programmer. Now a days almost everything is online, but what they would rather have you do instead of searching online is start understanding what functionality different classes and objects have built into them. Normally you wouldn't ever need those functionalities for this topic, you will eventually need them for other logic further down the line. Instead of providing you an answer as I think most will give you grief for posting homework here, is go and search on hashsets or ...

Comment: Find a way on how to load an array with current ids and add to them dynamically to the array and database by first checking the array to see if the value exists. There are a number of ways to do this. Depending on what your professor is looking for it may be of great benefit that you get a little creative with what you want, you may learn something you wouldn't have otherwise if we had provided you with one way that works for your needs.

Comment: @BrettReinhard ,Thanks! I'll keep that in mind..

Comment: @Positive as a relatively new student I feel your pain in trying to do things a different way while there is a better easier built in way of doing so. My advice would be think of 3 or 4 ways of phrasing your question and search google for them then append 'site:stackoverflow.com c#' to the end of the question if you haven't done so already.

Comment: RowCount is insufficient for the job: as soon as you delete a record, the result probably wont be unique/correct.